# Sed not matching one or more patterns

Tags: sed

I have this list of files:

```
$ more files
one_this_2017_1_abc.txt
two_that_2018_1_abc.txt
three_another_2017_10.abc.txt
four_again_2018_10.abc.txt
five_back_2018_1a.abc.txt
```

I would like to get this output:

```
one_this_XXXX_YY_abc.txt
two_that_XXXX_YY_abc.txt
three_another_XXXX_YY.abc.txt
four_again_XXXX_YY.abc.txt
five_back_XXXX_YY.abc.txt
```

I am trying to remove the year and the bit after the year and replace them with another string--this is to generate test cases.

I can get the year just fine, but it's that one or two character piece after it I can't seem to match.

This *should* work, right?

```
~/test_cases
$ cat files | sed -e 's/_[[:digit:]]\{4\}_/_XXXX_/' -e 's/_[[:alnum:]]\{1,2\}_/_YY_/'
one_this_XXXX_YY_abc.txt
two_that_XXXX_YY_abc.txt
three_another_XXXX_10.abc.txt
four_again_XXXX_10.abc.txt
five_back_XXXX_1a.abc.txt
```

Except it doesn't for the 2 character cases.

```
$ cat files | sed -e 's/_[[:digit:]]\{4\}_/_XXXX_/' -e 's/_[[:alnum:]]\
{2\}_/_YY_/'
one_this_XXXX_1_abc.txt
two_that_XXXX_1_abc.txt
three_another_XXXX_10.abc.txt
four_again_XXXX_10.abc.txt
five_back_XXXX_1a.abc.txt
```

Doesn't work for the two character cases either, and this works not at all (but according to the docs it should):

```
$ cat files | sed -e 's/_[[:digit:]]\{4\}_/_XXXX_/' -e 's/_[[:alnum:]]\+_/_YY_/'
one_YY_XXXX_1_abc.txt
two_YY_XXXX_1_abc.txt
three_YY_XXXX_10.abc.txt
four_YY_XXXX_10.abc.txt
five_YY_XXXX_1a.abc.txt
```

Other random experiments that don't work:

```
$ cat files | sed -e 's/_[[:digit:]]\{4\}_/_XXXX_/' -e 's/_[a-zA-Z0-9]\+_/_YY_/'
one_YY_XXXX_1_abc.txt
two_YY_XXXX_1_abc.txt
three_YY_XXXX_10.abc.txt
four_YY_XXXX_10.abc.txt
five_YY_XXXX_1a.abc.txt

$ cat files | sed -e 's/_[[:digit:]]\{4\}_/_XXXX_/' -e 's/_[a-zA-Z0-9]\{1\}_/_YY_/'
one_this_XXXX_YY_abc.txt
two_that_XXXX_YY_abc.txt
three_another_XXXX_10.abc.txt
four_again_XXXX_10.abc.txt
five_back_XXXX_1a.abc.txt

$ cat files | sed -e 's/_[[:digit:]]\{4\}_/_XXXX_/' -e 's/_[a-zA-Z0-9]\{2\}_/_YY_/'
one_this_XXXX_1_abc.txt
two_that_XXXX_1_abc.txt
three_another_XXXX_10.abc.txt
four_again_XXXX_10.abc.txt
five_back_XXXX_1a.abc.txt
```

Tried with both GNU sed version 4.2.1 under Linux and sed (GNU sed) 4.4 under Cygwin.

And yes, I realize I can pipe this through multiple sed calls to get it to work, but that regex SHOULD work, right?

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: The sample input is in there--I just  formatted it badly. 

I'll add what should be the output.

Answer (score 0):

if your Input_file is same as shown sample then following may help you in same.

```
sed 's/\([^_]*\)_\([^_]*\)_\(.*_\)\(.*\)/\1_\2_XXXX_YY_\4/g'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
one_this_XXXX_YY_abc.txt
two_that_XXXX_YY_abc.txt
three_another_XXXX_YY_10.abc.txt
four_again_XXXX_YY_10.abc.txt
five_back_XXXX_YY_1a.abc.txt
```

Comment: This same regex will be used for file name validation as well as the transforms, and the file names are (in this case) more regular. 

I'm more concerned with understanding what I'm doing wrong with the \{1,2\} and the \+ bits than I am solving this specific case.